# How to set a components state from another component?

Tags: reactjs

Here I have a weather app which uses an API in it's own component to fetch weather data. I'm at the point now where I'm trying to append the retrieved data values to the DOM/webpage but am having trouble. I have declared state in my Header component (working with only the Temp right now until it works) but can't figure how to manipulate it.

**Things I've tried and the outcomes:** I have tried putting the state into the top level as well as the API function (so it was all in App.js) but this didn't work because I couldn't call the nested function and if I make it global, it doesn't recognize the state variable. I also tried creating a function that explicitly changes state and using /importing that but I run into the same issue.

I have also theorized about maybe instead of trying to send the state to other components, to send the data to the component that holds the state (header) but I'm not sure on this since it's to my understanding that data should only live in one place? I appreciate any help.

APP.js

`

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header'
import Body from './components/body'
import Footer from './components/footer'
import { useState } from 'react';


function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
   <Header  />
    <Body />
    <Footer />
    
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

api.js

```
import {Header} from '../components/header'

export async function FetchAPI(location) {

    try {

    let result = await fetch ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location +'&APPID=bd3dd8d1151b1e784fcf021aa29927c5',
     {mode: 'cors'});

    let final = await result.json()

    return console.log(final.cod)
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert(err)
    }
}

export async function processData(data) {
    console.log(data)

    
}
```

Header.js

```
import {processData} from "../api/api"
import {useState} from 'react'



 export function Header({tempValue, locationValue}) {

  const handleTemp = (newValue) => { setTemp(newValue) }

  const [tempDOM, setTemp] = useState(2)

  return (
    <header className="header">
    <div>
   <h1 value={setTemp}> </h1>
   <h2></h2>
   </div>
   <div>
    <h1>Time</h1>
    <h2>Windspeed</h2>
    </div>
    </header>

  );

}




export default Header;
```

`

I have tried using state and changing that using a function as well as nesting the state and function that renders the data together in a top level component.

Comment: Data can transfer between parent and child components by props, you can set props by setState action, so you can set the parent state in child components.
In your code, there are having some code that is not valid
 return console.log(final.cod) => should return a valid rather than a console.log
         <h1 value={setTemp}> </h1> => <h1>{tempDOM}</h1>       
Looks like having a lot of varible/code that are not being used....

Answer (score 1):

While not necessary for this example, I would suggest you check out react stores. My personal favorite is **[MobX](https://mobx.js.org/react-integration.html)** - they can make managing your data a lot easier and reduce the amount of states and things you need to pass through to each components.

Now for your code here are a few notes:

1. You **don't seem to call FetchAPI from anywhere**. You should either call it on page load (in App.js) or call it inside your Header component when the location changes

   - Your **FetchAPI** also seems to **return a console.log()** not an actual value. I would suggest you return final.cod or whatever it is that you need returned. Perhaps even the entire json (**return final**)
2. Inside your h1 tag, you are setting the value to a set method of the state - this won't work. in useState, if you save it to an array, the first value (tempDOM) is the value of the state, and the second value is a method that is used to change the state value. So instead, as a comment has already suggested, use <h1>{tempDOM}</h1>. This will display the initial value you set (2) and nothing else since you are not changing the state value via setTemp() method

This is what I would expect the code to look like (haven't tested):

```
import './App.css';
import Header from './components/header'
import Body from './components/body'
import Footer from './components/footer'


function App() {

  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Header location='London'/>
      <Body />
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

```
import {FetchAPI} from "../api/api"
import {useState, useEffect} from 'react'


 export function Header({location}) {
  const [apiData, setApiData] = useState({});

  useEffect(()=>{
    async function getApiData() {
      const data = await FetchAPI(location);
      setApiData(data);
    }
    
    getApiData();
  // including location in useEffect dependency array,
  // which means this effect will be called every time location property changes
  }, [location]);

  return (
    <header className="header">
      <div>
        {
        // I don't know what your API model looks like.
        // adjust the property that you are accessing based on your knowledge
        }
        <h1>{apiData.temp}</h1>
        <h2></h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <h1>Time</h1>
        <h2>Windspeed</h2>
      </div>
    </header>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

```
export async function FetchAPI(location) {

    try {
      const result = await fetch ('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' + location +'&APPID=bd3dd8d1151b1e784fcf021aa29927c5',
     {mode: 'cors'});

      const final = await result.json()

      return final
    }
    catch(err) {
        alert(err)
    }
}
```

As mentioned, I **haven't tested** this, but this is more along the lines of what I would expect a working application to look like.

More on **[useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)**